# Delete Wifi Credentials from Raspbian cloned image

Tags: raspbian, networking, wifi, image

I have a custom Raspbian image (based on Raspbian lite + some additional software installs) and I would like to clone this image and distribute it as part of an opensource project. How can I delete the WiFi credentials or other sensitive information from the cloned image. I know that I can always delete the credentials before cloning but I would like to automate the process so would rather not modify the image on the sd card.

Comment: What do you want to do? Clone the master SD Card and then modify the cloned image before distributing?

Comment: Exactly, yes that's what I want to do. Sorry I wasn't clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to clone the master SD Card and then modify the cloned image before distributing it. I assume you use a raw image file as for example created with `dd`. Because the image file contains the raw partitions and filesystems of the original SD Card you cannot just edit it.You have to mount the partitions in the image file. Then you are able to modify it.

You can use `losetup` on the running master SD Card to mount the image. Because you have a modified Raspbian Lite you should find two partitions:

```
rpi ~$ sudo losetup --find --partscan --show cloned.img
rpi ~$ ls /dev/loop0*
/dev/loop0  /dev/loop0p1  /dev/loop0p2
```

`/dev/loop0p1` represents the first partition, which is the **fat32** boot partition and `/dev/loop0p2` is the **ext4** root partition. Just mount them:

```
rpi ~$ sudo mount /dev/loop0p2 /mnt
rpi ~$ sudo mount /dev/loop0p1 /mnt/boot
```

Now you can access and modify the images content. The boot partition with kernel and firmware you find at `/mnt/boot`.

When finished unmount and detach the image:

```
rpi ~$ sudo umount /mnt/boot
rpi ~$ sudo umount /mnt
rpi ~$ sudo losetup --detach-all
```

These are all commands on the commandline, so you should be able to automate the process with a bash script.